# Why do functions defined outside an event handler function need to be saved in new variables inside the event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, event-handling

javascript newbie here again.

I don't need to know *how* to do something, I just need help *understanding* something.

I just completed a coding challenge in a beginner book I am reading that asks you  to make a game in which the user has to search for the "buried treasure" on a treasure map. The game calculates the distance of each click from the randomly chosen location of the "treasure" and displays a different hotter/colder message until the player wins.

What I do not understand is why all the functions that I define outside the click event handler function need to be saved as new variables inside the event handler function. This totally confuses me. Why can't I just call those functions? See my entire script below:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//This function returns a random number that will be used as an argument to determine random coordinates for the location of the buried treasure.
var randomNumber = function (size) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*size);
}

//Variables used as arguments for the randomNumber function.
var width = 400;
var height = 400;

//Click counter variable.
var clicks = 0;

//Object representing the location of the buried treasure on the map.
var target = {
  x: randomNumber(width),
  y: randomNumber(height)
}

/* This function takes the event object and the buried treasure location object
and uses the Pythagorean theorem to determine a straight line between the click event
and the treasure location. Locations on the page and events on the page are always objects,
never simple variables containing a string or integer.
*/
var getDistance = function (event, target) {
  var diffX = event.offsetX - target.x;
  var diffY = event.offsetY - target.y;
  return Math.sqrt((diffX*diffX) + (diffY*diffY));
}

//This function takes distance as an argument and returns a message to the user depending on how far from the treasure location their click is.
var hints = function (distance) {
  if (distance < 10) {
    return "Red hot!";
  } else if (distance < 20) {
    return "Very hot!";
  } else if (distance < 40) {
    return "Hot";
  } else if (distance < 80) {
    return "Warm";
  } else if (distance < 160) {
    return "Cold";
  } else if (distance < 300) {
    return "Very cold!";
  } else {
    return "Ice cold! Brrrr";
  }
}

//Click handler function.
$("#map").click(function () {

  clicks++;

/* If you simply call the functions defined outside of the click handler function, the program will not
run correctly. Instead, the functions defined outside of the click handler function must be saved
in new variables and those variables used in the place of the functions in order for the program to
execute properly. This is what confuses me.
*/
  var distance = getDistance(event, target);
  var distanceHint = hints(distance);

  $("#hints").text(distanceHint);

  if (distance < 9) {
    alert("Treasure found in " + clicks + " clicks!");
  }

});




</script>
```

As you can see, the `getDistance` function and the `hints` function are saved in new variables inside the event handler. If I tried to simply call those functions inside the event handler without saving them to new variables first, the game would not work as intended. The same if I defined those functions inside the event handler and then called them. Could someone help me understand why this is the case? Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't assigning the function to the variable inside the event handler....you are assigning what the call of that function ***returns***.

In the case of the function reference assigned to variable `getDistance` when you call that function and pass in an `event` and a `target` it *returns* a calculated number. It is that calcualted number you are assigning to variable named `distance` to use elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

The variables `distance` and `distanceHint` are saved or to be more specific, assigned inside the event handler, not `getDistance` and `hints`.

In the following, `distance` and `distanceHint` are the new variables here and  the following simply means their values are assigned to `getDistance`'s and `hints`'s value and whenever the values of `getDistance` and `hints` are updated, they pass down the values to the `distance` and `distanceHint` variables respectively.

```
var distance = getDistance(event, target); // if getDistance(event, target) = ABC, then distance is now also equal to ABC
var distanceHint = hints(distance);// if hints(distance) = XYZ, then distanceHint is now also equal to XYZ
```